# Typescript "Generics" Syntax + Angle Brackets

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding the purpose behind angle brackets in Typescript.

Often, they're used for generics. This is clearest to me for functions. For example, if you've got a function that you want to make more reusable (or "generic") you'd apply them after the function name, like so:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T { 
  return arg; 
};
```

This enforces type safety while also allowing you to use this function with multiple types.

However, in other cases the `<` and `>` brackets appear *after* other types, like in the following event handler:

```
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  const val = e.currentTarget.value;
  setWord(val);
};
```

By looking at TypeScript's auto-completion feature, the `React.ChangeEvent` shows this: `React.ChangeEvent<Element>`

1. What does the `<Element>` mean in this case? Is it also a generic?
2. Are we passing in the `HTMLInputElement` in, and if so, is that an interface?
3. Finally, why is the generic in this case (if that's what's going on) passed *after* the `React.ChangeEvent` type, whereas with the function, the `T` generic is passed *before* the function body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` syntax shows what is called a [Generic Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-types). This type receives another type as "parameter" to further specify it better.

Think of a generic type similarly to a function, but for types. The functions we are used to receives one or more values and produce another value. Generic types are similar, they receive one or more types and produce a type. The generic type alone may or may not be enough to represent something, depending on whether or not it was declared with optional parameters (just like a function may or may not have optional parameters).

Here is a much simpler example of generic type: `Array<T>`. This is just another way of saying `T[]`. For example, `Array<number>`. Another very common generic type is `Promise<T>`, which represents the type of a promise that resolves to `T`.

The `Promise` is a good example of a generic type whose parameter is *required*:

```
// --------------------------------------
// | interface Promise<T>               |
// --------------------------------------
// | Represents the completion of an    |
// | asynchronous operation             |
// --------------------------------------
// | Generic type 'Promise<T>' requires |
// | 1 type argument(s).   ts(2314)     |
// --------------------------------------
//          ^
//          |
//          |
type X = Promise;
```

Let's say you want to represent an object with the form `{ foo: something }` where something can be whatever you want. You would do this with a generic type:

```
type Foo<SomeType> = {
  foo: SomeType;
};

// Now you can declare specific types

type FooWithString = Foo<string>;
// equivalent of:
// type FooWithString = { foo: string };

type FooWithNumber = Foo<number>;
// equivalent of:
// type FooWithString = { foo: number };
```

If we want to make this `SomeType` an optional type parameter, so that our generic type `Foo` can also be used by itself (without passing a type via angle brackets), we just have to decide what we want its default type to be (similarly to how we can choose default values for normal functions):

```
type Foo<SomeType = Date> = {
  foo: SomeType;
};
```

Now we can use `Foo` without angle brackets - it would be equivalent of doing `Foo<Date>`.

---

You can find several interesting examples of types like this in the [TypeScript reference for Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html).

---

**Explicit answers to your questions:**

**1.** The `<Element>` shows the generic type being hovered by you (i.e. `React.ChangeEvent`) receives one type parameter, and the person from React team that created this generic type decided to call this parameter `Element`.

- In my example above, if you hover upon `Foo<number>` it will show you `Foo<SomeType>`, because that's how I declared the type.

**2a.** Yes, we are passing the `HTMLInputElement` as a parameter to the generic type `React.ChangeEvent`. Think of `React.ChangeEvent` like a "type function" that takes a type parameter and "returns" another type. So we give `HTMLInputElement` to `React.ChangeEvent` so that the resulting type `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` specifies what we want.

**2b.** Being or not being an interface is not relevant. An `interface` is just a syntax to declare a type that has a few quirks compared to a standard `type Foo = /* ... */`. Don't worry about these details now.

**3.** This is just how TypeScript developers decided the syntax should be. It matches the syntax of Java, for example, in which we have generic types such as `ArrayList<String>` and generic functions such as `myFunc<SomeType>(a: SomeType)`.

Comment: Bravo, this is really a fantastic answer. Thank you!

Comment: @HarryCramer Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

`ChangeEvent` like your function can be passed a type, so you're passing a concrete type into it. You could also pass a concrete type into your function - `identity<MyType>(myArg)` although you probably don't need to as the type will be inferred from the argument you pass in since they both share `T`.

The difference is that `ChangeEvent` can't infer the type from an argument as it's not a function so you need to explicitly give it one.

`HTMLInputElement` could be a `type` or `interface`. The `ChangeEvent` will vary depending on the HTML element type (a change from an `input` is different from a change of a `select`) so you pass in what type of element it is to get the complete final interface back.